# What is fault in below shellscript, as i got error for "fi" when running this script?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

```
fileloc=/shellscript/ScriptDeleteLogs/Testfiles/Testdata/*
for fname in fileloc
do
name=$(basename "$fileloc")
if [ $name = $omitfiles ] then
echo $name
fi
done
```

i am trying to get file names from directory but when i apply filter i.e. if condition it throws error i.e. syntax error near unexpected token 'fi' and for 'then'
Formatted condition:

`if [ "$name" != "$omitfiles" ]; then
echo $name
fi`

Comment: Use `if [ "$name" = "$omitfiles" ]; then`

Comment: FYI 'omitfiles' array of filenames which needs to be omitted

Comment: Thanks anubhava..but my array 'declare -a omitfiles=("App.log" "app.pid" "app_security.log")' and  i changed the condition 'if  [ "$name" != "$omitfiles" ]'.....still output showing files content in omitfiles.

Comment: Why not try a nested "for loop"?

Comment: @koolomi: the other thing that @anubhava mentioned is putting a semicolon before the `then` keyword.

Comment: Check your syntax with http://shellcheck.net/ before posting here. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Either you insert a linebreak after the if condition:

```
...
if [ "$name" = "$omitfiles" ]
then
...
```

or you put a semicolon after the condition:

```
...
if [ "$name" = "$omitfiles" ]; then
...
```

And of course the variables in the condition should be double-quoted.

Comment: yes, i am following the semicolon way,  stil  output showing files in array **omitfiles**                                                                                                  please see above formatted code.

Comment: You don't show the content of `omitfiles`, so it's hard to comment on this, but if it is really an **array** as you say, it doesn't make much sense to compare a single value (`$name`) to a whole array (`$omitfiles`) for equality. Add `set -x` on the top of your script and see what's going on.